# Need to Customize PhoneGap Build for Andriod ver. 6 & 7

Tags: android, phonegap, phonegap-cli, mendix

We are facing issue in Phone Gap app as below,
Default app is supporting Android 8, 9 & 10 but we require to install .APK file in Android version 6 & 7.
While generating the build, we tried to customize the version of **Phone Gap CLI** to 6.5.0 in `config.xml` file.
And while installing we are getting error message as:

> There was a problem paring the package.

PFA for reference
Kindly provide a solution to make it compatible to support Android version 6 & 7. 
[image: screenshot dialog]